# How to translate a scalar subquery into a conditional OLAP function in SQL?

Tags: sql, nested, teradata, olap

I am using Teradata 15.10. I have a table with two columns last_name and first_name. For each row, I need to count how many others rows have the same last_name and first_name, but with the values reversed, and display that count (even if it is equal to 0). For the moment, I am using this query :

```
SELECT LAST_NAME, 
       FIRST_NAME,
      (SELECT Count(*)
       FROM   myTable AS T1
       WHERE  T1.FIRST_NAME = T2.LAST_NAME
         AND  T1.LAST_NAME  = T2.FIRST_NAME) AS REVERSE_NAME_COUNT
FROM myTable AS T2
```

Unfortunately this is not very fast and I have a lot of others columns where I am doing this kind of count. I was wondering if there is a way to translate the scalar subquery above into an OLAP function like this :

```
SUM(CASE WHEN T1.FIRST_NAME = T2.LAST_NAME AND T1.LAST_NAME = T2.FIRST_NAME THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
```

But from what I understand there is no way to access the values currently being processed in a partition. Is there any other way I could write my subquery ?

Input example :

```
       FIRST_NAME        LAST_NAME
----------------------------------
           SYLVIE           BOUVET
         LUCIENNE             BRUN
           BOUVET           SYLVIE
         FRANCINE            CARON
             BRUN         LUCIENNE
             BRUN         LUCIENNE
            KEVIN         MACHETEL
             REMI        MINVIELLE
          QUENTIN        THUILLIER
        MINVIELLE             REMI
```

Desired output example :

```
       FIRST_NAME        LAST_NAME  REVERSE_NAME_COUNT
------------------------------------------------------
           SYLVIE           BOUVET                   1
         LUCIENNE             BRUN                   2
           BOUVET           SYLVIE                   1
         FRANCINE            CARON                   0
             BRUN         LUCIENNE                   1
             BRUN         LUCIENNE                   1
            KEVIN         MACHETEL                   0
             REMI        MINVIELLE                   1
          QUENTIN        THUILLIER                   0
        MINVIELLE             REMI                   1
```

Comment: Your first query makes no sense.  Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I edited for more details and desired output.

Comment: Your calculating the info that *last_name* `BRUN` exists in three other rows as *first_name*? For how many column combination do you want to calculate this? What is your final goal, showing those counts for each and every row or just display those rows with `count>0`?

Comment: Thanks @dnoeth. I was indeed trying to count the reversed last name and first name for every row, and display those counts for each row (even when count = 0). I edited my initial post to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you talking about a *Scalar Subquery* in Select?

```
SELECT
   last_name
  ,(
     SELECT Count(*)
     FROM   myTable AS T1
     WHERE  T1.FIRST_NAME = T2.LAST_NAME
   )
FROM myTable AS t2
```

Then you're right, you can't rewrite it as an OLAP function.

Those Scalar Subqueries tend do have bad performance, but you can usually rewrite them using an Outer Join:

```
SELECT
   t2.last_name
  ,t1.Cnt 
FROM myTable AS t2 
LEFT JOIN
 ( 
   SELECT first_name, Count(*) AS Cnt
   FROM myTable
   GROUP BY 1
 ) AS t1
ON T1.FIRST_NAME = T2.LAST_NAME
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I am trying to achieve. Is the outer join faster than the standard scalar subquery ? The problem is I have a lot of fields where I want to do this kind of operation.

Comment: Replacing a Scalar Subquery with an Outer Join might greatly improve performance, at least it should never reduce it.

Comment: Your answer gave me the solution but was not exactly what I wanted as my initial post was not very clear. I provided the solution below.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @dnoeth I found the solution.

```
SELECT
   T2.first_name
   T2.last_name
  ,SUM(t1.Cnt) 
FROM myTable AS T2 
LEFT JOIN
 ( 
   SELECT first_name, last_name, Count(*) AS Cnt
   FROM myTable
   GROUP BY 1, 2
 ) AS T1
ON T1.first_name = T2.last_name
AND T1.last_name = T2.first_name
GROUP BY 1, 2
```